# How to have two ControllerAdvice in the same SpringMvc application

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I would like to manage Exception thrown by simple Controller or RestController in two ways: 
1) html redirection
2) Json error

I tested the code below :

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class ExceptionHandlerController
{
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleException(HttpServletRequest _req, Exception _ex)
    {
        K_LOGGER.info("test");
        return new ModelAndView();
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class ExceptionHandlerRestController
{

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(HttpServletRequest _req, Exception _ex)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("test", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}

@RestController
public class GreetingController
{
    @RequestMapping("/greetingexception")
    public Greeting greetingException(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name)
        throws Exception
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

It doesn't work properly, I always pass by ExceptionHandlerController but not by ExceptionHandlerRestController.

I think it's because @RestController inherit of @Controller.

Do you have a other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) annotation to rest exception handler. It may helps you.

Comment: Thx lot, it works. Why the precedence is important? Spring applies ControllerAdvices according to the loading order ?

Comment: In this case he took first defined, cause they handle the same exception. When resolver tries to find handler for exception he take first defined if you did not provide an order.

Answer (score 3):

*eg04lt3r* answer is correct, just though that more details might be useful for someone.

In case when you have global `@ControllerAdvice` and want to handle some exception in a different way in one of your Controllers you need to set `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on the `@ControllerAdvice` which should have higher priority.

For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Error> handleException(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = MyController.class)
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Error> handleException(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`@Order` is needed because on startup one of the handlers will register with higher order automatically, anyway and your exception handling will become unpredictable. For example I recently saw a case when if you start an app using bootRun gradle task `MyExceptionHandler` was primary, but when started as jar `GeneralExceptionHandler` was primary.